# Group items from column using awk

Tags: awk, sed, cut, trim

Trying to do the following, 
I have txt file which as the data of the interfaces.

```
Eth1/15       desc01   1
Eth101/1/11   desc01   1
Eth101/1/16   desc01   1
Eth103/1/21   desc01   1
Eth1/2        desc01   1
Eth1/24       desc01   1
Eth103/1/5    desc01   1
Gi0/1         desc01   1
Gi0/0/1       desc01   1
Gi0/1/1       desc01   1
```

Wanted to find out the common Interface type
Expected results:

If `/` contains twice then count the matching, else just `Gi0` or `Eth1`

`Eth1, Eth101/1, Eth103/1, Gi0, Gi0/0, Gi0/1`

I tried using the AWK, what but not getting the results.
`cat findint.txt | egrep 'Eth|Gi' | awk -F"/" '{print $1}'`

I tried following

`cat findint.txt | egrep 'Eth|Gi' | \
 awk '{print substr($1, 0, length($1)-2)}' | sort -u`

Results, some values are repeated which I don't.

Expected Results:
`Eth1, Eth101/1, Eth103/1, Gi0, Gi0/0, Gi0/1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -F"/" '!seen[$1]++ {print $1}' findint.txt 
Eth1
Eth101
Eth103
Gi0
```

To get the output all in one comma-separated line, you could set the output separator `ORS` to `,` however you'd need to make a special case for the the last value; a simpler way is to pipe the output of `awk` to `paste`:

```
awk -F"/" '!seen[$1]++ {print $1}' findint.txt | paste -sd,
```

Comment: Thanks, never use `seen` interesting

Comment: @netkool `seen` is just an array - its name is arbitrary (you could use `a[$1]++` or `foo[$1]++` etc.)

Comment: @netkool, this is a awk idiom to do something only the very first time some field is encountered.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver for the explanation, make sense now, is it possible to print in one line with comma Eth1,Eth101,Eth103,Gi0 removing the `\n` thanks

Comment: @netkool please see updated answer

Comment: @steeldriver I would like to get the following output, is there any way to capture `/1/` as well
```
Eth1
Eth101/1
Eth103/1
Gi0
```

Comment: From the above text file, like to get the extra `/` as well so the expected result:
`Eth1
Eth101/1
Eth103/1
Gi0
`

Comment: @netkool if you have additional requirements, please edit your question - it's hard to understand what you are asking given the limits of code formating in comments

Comment: hi @steeldriver I did update the expected answer, what I was looking is:
` Eth1 Eth101/1  Eth103/1  Gi0 `
wanted to capture the middle value `/1/`